# Xamarin two activities with one button on each: Second activities button onClick seems bound before the activity is live

Tags: android, xamarin

I've got a starter xamarin app.  My MainActivity has a button on it that, when clicked, loads a second activity that also has a button on it.  clicking *that* button will increase a counter (just like the helloworld app).

Here's my MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "SpellbookXamarin", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button myButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            myButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SpellActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
        }
    }
```

And here's my SpellActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Spell")]
    public class SpellActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            int count = 0;
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // and attach an event to it
            Button spellbutton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            spellbutton.Click += delegate { spellbutton.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

Whenever I load the application and click `MyButton` (the one in MainActivity), a `NullReferenceException` occurs referencing spellButton's click event.  But that shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second Activity called SpellActivity. You never set any content view just like in the first.

So either reuse Resource.Layout.Main or make a new layout with a button and call:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mylayout);
```

right after `base.OnCreate(bundle);`

If you create a new layout, remember to give the button an Id to be able to use FindViewById

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!